# Is there a short way to parse XML string in Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have explored many websites but failed to find any SIMPLE example or answer about parsing xml.

In fact websites are full of examples and answers but these are so lengthy and complex.
Please answer me a simple way to parse XML String and get its elements. Thanks.

Comment: and please do not refer to your website

Comment: `Pull` and `SAX` are very simple, because the `XML` file does have the complexity.

Comment: The question is so broad because the [encouraged way](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml) of parsing XML in Android is strikingly complex and horrible in every way - suggested options of using STaX directly are fragile and prone to errors. So, the problem is not the broadness of the question - the problem is how horrible XML parsing solutions typically are on Android. You can try [konsume-xml](https://gitlab.com/mvysny/konsume-xml), disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this,

```
 public void parseXml(){
    try {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput( new StringReader( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) ); // pass input whatever xml you have
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Start document");
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Start tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                Log.d(TAG,"End tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Text "+xpp.getText()); // here you get the text from xml
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"End document");

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering it helps me every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parse xml using XMLPullParser. Below is the Handler class -

```
public class XmlPullParserHandler {

    String text;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public String parse(InputStream is) {

        try {

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(is, null);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("YOUR_TAG1")) {
                            builder.append("TAG1 = " + text);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("YOUR_TAG2")) {
                            builder.append("\nTAG2 = " + text);
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }


}
```

To parse the XML response fetched from WebService and read in Inputstream you can do as below -

```
XmlPullParserHandler parser = new XmlPullParserHandler();
InputStream is = "YOUR XML RESPONSE";
String xmlOutput = parser.parse(is);
```

xmlOutput is a string containing all parsed xml values.